# PHP failed to open stream

Tags: php

Стоял на сервере скрипт который работал с апи фейсбука год.

```
$json_object = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/feed?fields=permalink_url&limit=5&access_token=' . $access_token);
```

Теперь хостер что-то намутил и все полетело(на локалке все продолжает работать), не доходят запросы до фейсбука. Я так понимаю они поменяли параметр `allow_url_fopen`. Как переписать под cUrl этот запрос? или еще как-то решить вопрос что бы заработало? Сейчас пишет:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(***): failed to open stream: В соединении отказано in ***.php on line 18

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ***.php on line 26

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ***.php on line 28
```

Переписал под curl:

```
// 1. инициализация  
$ch = curl_init();  
// 2. указываем параметры, включая url  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/****/feed?fields=permalink_url&limit=5&access_token=****");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
// 3. получаем HTML в качестве результата  
$output = curl_exec($ch);  
 echo $output;
 if ($output === FALSE) {  
    //Тут-то мы о ней и скажем  
    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);  
    return;  
}  
// 4. закрываем соединение  
curl_close($ch);
```

Получил:

```
cURL Error: couldn't connect to host
```

Может в https проблема?

Comment: попробуй CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  false, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  false

Comment: добавил эти опции, все равно cURL Error: couldn't connect to host